# where is the location of install apk nmanifiest file

Tags: android

I'm installing my project apk file on device and I can view all its database inside

```
/data/data/com.myapp
```

but did not find manifest file.

I go on

```
data/data/myapp
```

and I find only libs and database. I want to find manifiest file. How can I find the manifest file?

**Note**

My device is rooted.

Comment: Please follow the instructions on how to post a question in SO.

Answer (score 0):

The `AndroidManifest.xml` gets bundled by AAPT into the .apk file. It is not stored by itself on the file system.

For more information please look at how [`Building and Running`](http://developer.android.com/tools/building/index.html) is performed.

Comment: You can't by browsing the file system. If you developed the application it should be the same as the one you can see via your IDE given that you didn't modify it after the app was installed.

Comment: no any posibility android provide to get location of manifiest or open manifiest file in text editor inside phone???????

Comment: No, there is not a way to do that.